# Count on react hook state change before act

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-state, react-state-management

I'm having a hard time using react state and need your help.

I'm using custom hooks to validate some kind of form. 
I'm using another hook to control the system status at each moment. 
the problem is that after validation, the status is not updating fast enough.

I'm adding a basic scenario to example my problem.

MainComponent.tsx (form)

```
import * as React from "react";

const MainComponent = () => {
  const [state1, setState1] = React.useState({});
  const [state2, setState2] = React.useState({});
  const {validateAll, errors} = userValidator(state1, state2)
  const {status} = useStatus(errors)

  const handleClick = () => {
    validateAll()
    console.log(status) // after validating, status is still not ok
    if (status === "ok") {
      runWhatEver()
    } else {
      console.log("getting in here :(")
      runAnotherThing()
    }
    console.log(status) // here its "ok" already
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
    ....
    </div>
  );
}
```

useValidator.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import {validateState1, validateState2} from "validator.ts"

const userValidator = (state1, state2) => {
    const [state1Errors, setState1Errors] = useState<any>({});
    const [state2Errors, setState2Errors] = useState<any>({});

    const validateState1UsingValidator = (newValue) => {
      setState1Errors({
        state1: validateState1(state1)
      })
    }

    const validateState2UsingValidator = (newValue) => {
      setState2Errors({
        state1: validateState2(state2)
      })
    }

    const validateAll = () => {
      validateState1();
      validateState2();
    }

    return {validateAll, errors: {state1Errors, state2Errors}}
}
```

validator.ts

```
export const validateState1 = (newValue) => {
  if (newValue.length <= 3) {
    return "valuelength  must be greater than 3";
  }
}

export const validateState2 = (newValue) => {
  if (newValue.length <= 3) {
    return "valuelength  must be greater than 3";
  }
}
```

useStatus.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

const useStatus = (errors) => {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState("not ok");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasNoErrors()) {
      setStatus("ok")
    } else {
      setStatus("not ok")
    }
  }, [errors])

  return {status}
}
```

I know that state change is async, but is there any way to make it work as expected?
other approaches are welcome but this demo is little compared to the real problem so I dont know if a whole different approach can work.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You are importing functions from `validator.ts`, then re-declaring them: `import {validateState1, validateState2} from "validator.ts"
` I am surprised it is even working. try changing function names in `useValidator.tsx`

Comment: it's just a demo I wrote to describe the problem. edited for the sake of readibility